# Review form in magento2.2

Tags: php, frontend, ajax, magento2.2, requirejs

I have modified the review form as popup modal in my custom module. And now How to submit a Review form in ajax and need to pass the submitted values to controller, Please provide me a solution.
My js will look like below before ajax submission

**js file**

```
 define(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function (jQuery, modal) {
    return function (config) {

        var customFunction = {
            ajaxSubmit: function () {
                var nickname = jQuery("#nickname_field").val();

                var review = jQuery("#review_field").val();

                var rating = jQuery(".field required review-field-ratings").val();

                alert(nickname);
                alert(review);
                alert(rating);
                var reviewurl = config.url;
                alert(reviewurl);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: reviewurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    //Order id and reason passed to the controller
                    data: {'nickname': nickname, 'review': review, 'rating': rating, },
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("successful");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("failed");
                    }
                });
            },

            options: {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: jQuery.mage.__('Product Review'),
                buttons: [{
                        text: jQuery.mage.__('submit'),
                        class: '',
                        click: function () {
                            //Ajax function call
                            customFunction.ajaxSubmit();
                            var close = this;
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                close.closeModal();

                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    }]
            }
        };
        jQuery(".product-reviews-summary").on('click', function () {
            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
        jQuery(".add-review").on('click', function () {
            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
        jQuery(".star-popup").on('click', function () {
            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code for ajax call and Post data to controller :

```
define(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function (jQuery, modal) {
    return function (config) {

        var customFunction = {
            options: {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: jQuery.mage.__('Product Review'),
                 buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('submit'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function(data) {

                        var form_data = jQuery("#form-id").serialize();


                        console.log(form_data);
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php  echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'frontname/controllername/actionname';?>",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: form_data,
                            success: function(data) {

                                console.log(data);
                            },
                            error: function(result) {
                                console.log('no response !');
                            }
                        });

                        this.closeModal();

                    }
                }]
            }
        };
        jQuery(".product-reviews-summary").on('click', function () {
            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
        jQuery(".add-review").on('click', function () {
            modal(customFunction.options, jQuery('#popup-modal'));
            jQuery("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");

        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Befor I have submitted the data directly to the core controller

Comment: Now, Am I need to override (Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post.php) core controller in my custom module

Comment: I need to get the submitted form fields and need to pass it to the controller

Comment: you can directly post data to core controller

Comment: But in core controller they wrote code for form reload . But I dont want to reload the form after submitted so I need to override that, any suggestion

Comment: then you need to override controller and write code for handle ajax request

Comment: I have overrided the core controller, But am I need to copy all the contents what is present in core controller

Comment: can you please tell me which core controller you have overriden?

Comment: Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post.php

Comment: in that only execute() method is implemented so you need to copy all content of file

Comment: whether it prevent reloading after the form is submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70429/discussion-between-sri-and-mansi).